# How to convert Hex to binary in excel 2013 , then save each bit in different cell

Tags: hex, excel-2013, bin

I want to convert Hex number to binary and then each bit of that binary should be saved in different cell. is it possible to do in excel 2013.
for e.g. 
hexno. B
binary: 1011,
then 1,0,1,1 should be stored separately in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say hexadecimal value is in A1 then to convert to binary, say in B1:

```
=HEX2BIN(A1)
```

[HEX2BIN](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/HEX2BIN-function-a13aafaa-5737-4920-8424-643e581828c1).

From there you might use a formula in C1 and copy it across to the right as suitable:

```
=MID($B1,COLUMN()-2,1)
```

but assuming you have several numbers to deal with I suggest don't fill your sheet with formulae but apply Text to Columns. Copy formula results in ColumnB and Paste Special...., Values over the top. Select ColumnB, DATA - Data Tools, Text to Columns, Fixed width, parse at every required individual character position, <kbd>Finish</kbd>.